# find -prune: why does -print0 affect search results?

Tags: find

Scenario:

```
$ tree .
.
├── x1.txt
├── x2.txt
└── x3.txt

0 directories, 3 files

$ find . -name "x1.txt" -prune -o -name "*.txt"
./x1.txt
./x2.txt
./x3.txt

$ find . -name "x1.txt" -prune -o -name "*.txt" -print0
./x2.txt./x3.txt
```

Here we see that `-print0` does affect search results. Confused.

Why does presence of `-print0` cause `find ...` to not print `x1.txt`?

Why does absence of `-print0` cause `find ...` to print `x1.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find`’s default action (used whenever no action other than `-prune` or `-quit` is specified) is `-print`; in

```
find . -name "x1.txt" -prune -o -name "*.txt"
```

there’s an implied `-print` in all cases:

```
find . -name "x1.txt" -prune -print -o -name "*.txt" -print
```

or more accurately,

```
find . \( -name "x1.txt" -prune -o -name "*.txt" \) -print
```

Adding `-print0` removes that default, so

```
find . -name "x1.txt" -prune -o -name "*.txt" -print0
```

means “if the name matches `x1.txt`, prune it; otherwise, if it matches `*.txt`, print it, with a null terminator”.